# cant use DescendantNodes in where in linq to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a class with xml field like this:

```
Public System.Xml.Linq.XElement ProductAttributeXML {get;set;}
```

I have a query like belowe :

```
var query = (from product in db.ProductAttributeCombinations
                     where product.ProductAttributeXML.DescendantNodes().Count()>0
                     select product

                         );
        var x = query.ToList();
```

but when run project and when `ToList()` I getting this Error :

> Method 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Xml.Linq.XNode] DescendantNodes()' has no supported translation to SQL.

how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DescendantNodes()` can't convert `SQL function`. I think, if you get data with `ToList()` this function works in code side. Please try this:

```
 var query = (from product in db.ProductAttributeCombinations.ToList()//add ToList() here                 
              where product.ProductAttributeXML.DescendantNodes().Count()>0
              select product
              );
```